# Use Eclipse with gfortran: how to make MINPACK operationizable?

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran, dynamic-linking

I am using ECLIPSE PHP package as a Fortran interface to write my f95 code. I then compile it using the ECLIPSE interface on my mac Yosemite. I understand that the underlying compiler is `gfortran`, which I installed using terminal.

Now I need to minimize a multivariable function and what to use Minpack package found here: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/minpack/minpack.html

I copy the code into a module named minpack. When I try to compile I get:

```
"_enorm_", referenced from:
  ___minpack_MOD_qrfac in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_lmstr in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_lmpar in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_lmdif in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_lmder in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_hybrj in minpack.o
  ___minpack_MOD_hybrd in minpack.o
  ...
```

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I understand I somehow have to link the `minpack` library to `gfortran`--- how to do this?

Comment: Don't use tags for individual Fortran (or other languages) version without the main one. The same way you uses c++ and not c++-98. More people will see your question.

Comment: You are just missing the `enorm()` subroutine or function. Search for its source code.